# Calling Oracle stored procedure with XMLTYPE input and output parameters with Python and Cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures, cx-oracle, xmltype

I'm trying to run a Oracle stored procedure using Python and Cx_Oracle 8.2.1. This procedure has two XMLTYPE arguments, one for input and one for output, it would be called like so in Oracle and works OK:

```
DECLARE 
   RXML_OUT XMLTYPE;
BEGIN 
   RXML_OUT := NULL;
   MYPACKAGE.MYPROCEDURE ( IN_SXML, RXML_OUT );
END;
```

However, I've been unable to call it using Cx_Oracle. I'm trying to call it like so:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(config["db"]["usuario"], config["db"]["password"], 
    "{}/{}".format(config["db"]["host"], config["db"]["servicio"]), encoding=config["db"]["nls_charset"],
    nencoding=config["db"]["nls_ncharset"])

cursor = connection.cursor()

xml_in = """
    <myxml>
        <sometag>This is some XML</sometag>
    </myxml>
    """

rxml_out = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)

res = cursor.callproc('MYPACKAGE.MYPROCEDURE', [xml_in, rxml_out])[1]
```

I can run other procedures with other data types and regular queries without problems. However, with this one, I get the following error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROCEDURE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROCEDURE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

As far as I could gather from the documentation, Cx_Oracle does not have a XML datatype, and that XMLTYPE can be treated as strings if under about 1 GB (these XML files I'm handling are some KBs in length at most, so I'm well under that limit). What am I doing wrong here?

### Update 1

I've tried using temporary CLOBs, [as shown in the documentation here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/xml_data_type.html). The result is the same (please note, our DBA actually modified the procedure so that only the first parameter is XMLTYPE IN, the second is VARCHAR OUT):

```
xml_in = connection.createlob(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB)
xml_in.write("""
    <myxml>
        <sometag>This is some XML</sometag>
    </myxml>
    """)
po_msgerror = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)

po_msgerror.setvalue(0, "")

cursor.callproc('MYPACKAGE_PKG.MYPROCEDURE', [xml_in, po_msgerror])
```

The end result is the same as before:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 
'MYPROCEDURE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

### Update 2

I also tried using an anonymous PL/SQL block for calling the procedure, [as shown in the documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html) (same code snippet as before, but using the execute method instead of callproc):

```
#cursor.callproc('MYPACKAGE_PKG.MYPROCEDURE', [xml_in, po_msgerror])
cursor.execute("""BEGIN 
        MYPACKAGE_PKG.MYPROCEDURE ( :1, :2 );
    END;
    """, [xml_in, po_msgerror])
```

The result is still the same:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROCEDURE'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Review https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/xml_data_type.html and use similar techniques for passing data in, and fetching it back as a CLOB.  You'll likely need an anonymous PL/SQL block called from cx_Oracle that then calls your procedure.  If you update your question with a runnable example (include SQL to create the procedure) we can give more detail.

Comment: Thanks Christopher! I tried that (using CLOBs for both IN and OUT parameters, as shown in the documentation you point to), it didn't work... I'll update my question with what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting a lot, I was finally able to successfully call the procedure and pass an XMLTYPE input parameter. The following code worked (the procedure takes two parameters, a XMLTYPE IN and a VARCHAR OUT):

```
# Consumo de package para envío del XML de prestaciones
xml_in = """
    <myxml>
        <sometag>This is some XML</sometag>
    </myxml>
    """

po_msgerror = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
po_msgerror.setvalue(0, "")

cursor.execute("""BEGIN 
    MYPACKAGE_PKG.MYPROCEDURE ( sys.xmltype(:1), :2 );
    END;
    """, [xml_in, po_msgerror])
```

There was no need to use a CLOB for the XMLTYPE IN parameter, a string worked just fine. Calling the procedure using an anonymous PL/SQL block and explicitly passing the first parameter as sys.xmltype was enough.

I don't know if I could just cast an XMLTYPE OUT parameter in the same fashion and bind it to a string variable. But at least for input parameters, this worked just fine.